# Ruby Lambda's giving an undefined method when used with myfunc.(someparam)

Tags: ruby, lambda, sinatra

just wading in to the world of Ruby, and standing up a Sinatra based API.

Here's one of my route definitions.  not_found works when called as &not_found, but it gives '2015-10-23 16:31:59 - NoMethodError - undefined method `status' for Sinatra::FileService::GetFiles:Module:' when called as 'not_found.( params['obsId'] )'.

Anyone have any direction that they could provide?  Much appreciated!

```
 def self.registered(app)

    not_found = -> id = 'undefined' {
      status 404
      content_type :json
      { 
        :message => settings.messages['get']['404'], 
        :data => {
          id: _id
        } 
      }.to_json
    }

    found = -> _id { 
      status 200
      content_type :json
      { 
        :message => settings.messages['get']['200'], 
        :data => {
          :id => _id
        }
      }.to_json
    }

    app.get '/', &not_found

    app.get '/:obsId' do

      if params['obsId'] == '1'
        found.( params['obsId'] )
      else 
        not_found.( params['obsId'] )
      end

    end

  end
```

Comment: You sure you want period in there? `not_found.( params['obsId'] )` doesn't look right to me. Try `not_found[params['obsId']]` or `not_found.call(params['obsId'])`.

Comment: I'm using "ruby 2.0.0p481" which supports .() rather than .call() I believe.  (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: My bad. So much to keep up with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that it was a scoping issue.  It seems like when you call lambda with default param(s), it maintains outer scope.  But when you pass in params, it creates a new inner scope.

Updating my call to `found.call( params['obsId'], settings.messages['get']['200'] )` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Ruby 1.8 by any chance? The `.()` syntax did not exist back then. You have to use one of the following two notations in 1.8:

```
found[params['obsId']]

found.call(params['obsId'])
```

But in Ruby 1.8 the `-> {}` syntax to define lambdas also did not exist. You might run into more errors and need to replace your lambda definition with

```
found = lambda do |id|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.0.0p481.  I'll try with older style syntax.

Comment: Double check your ruby version, from inside your script. Sometimes it is possible that RVM/Rbenv is configured incorrectly and you are running on a system Ruby.